# Maximum length of a cursor name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cursor

I am creating a program to automate the generation of procedures which have cursors in it, and I am having some trouble when running the generated procedures, specifically about the length of the cursor name, so

What is the maximum length of a cursor name in MySQL?

Comment: Can you tell us if you are experiencing any errors

Comment: I'd say: more than you will ever need, and if you ever reach the limit, then there is something wrong in your code. But interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: I have successfully created a cursor with a name > 1000 characters. What is your actual error? Please post the exact error message.